# Three identical servers -- all accept a 61 kilobyte file over scp, but two refuse anything over 62 kilobytes

Tags: ubuntu, networking, scp

I've got three VM servers, running the same Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Identifiers, with an incremental IP range:

```
99.99.99.140
99.99.99.141
99.99.99.142
```

One of them (.141) is giving serious issues when sending data to *any* host on the world wide web.
I'm running a super simple test to copy a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# scp-speed-test.sh
# Author: Alec Jacobson alecjacobsonATgmailDOTcom
#
# Test ssh connection speed by uploading and then downloading a 10000K test
# file (optionally user-specified size)
#
# Usage:
#   ./scp-speed-test.sh user@hostname [test file size in KBs]
#

ssh_server=$1
test_file=".scp-test-file"

test_size=$2

# generate a x kilobytes random file
echo "Generating $test_size KB test file..."
`dd if=/dev/urandom of=$test_file bs=$(echo "$test_size*1024" | bc) \
  count=1 &> /dev/null`

# upload test
echo "Testing upload to $ssh_server..."
up_speed=`scp -v $test_file $ssh_server:$test_file 2>&1 | \
  grep "Bytes per second" | \
  sed "s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\).*$/\1/g"`
up_speed=`echo "($up_speed*0.0009765625*100.0+0.5)/1*0.01" | bc`

# download test
echo "Testing download to $ssh_server..."
down_speed=`scp -v $ssh_server:$test_file $test_file 2>&1 | \
  grep "Bytes per second" | \
  sed "s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\).*$/\2/g"`
down_speed=`echo "($down_speed*0.0009765625*100.0+0.5)/1*0.01" | bc`

# clean up
echo "Removing test file on $ssh_server..."
`ssh $ssh_server "rm $test_file"`
echo "Removing test file locally..."
`rm $test_file`

# print result
echo ""
echo "Upload speed:   $up_speed KB/s"
echo "Download speed: $down_speed KB/s"
```

When uploading to all three servers with a **61** kilobytes file, it all succeeds fine:

```
ZENBOOK:~$ ./scp-speed-test.sh root@99.99.99.140 61
Generating 61 KB test file...
Testing upload to root@99.99.99.140...
Testing download to root@99.99.99.140...
Removing test file on root@99.99.99.140...
Removing test file locally...

Upload speed:   78.98 KB/s
Download speed: 73.88 KB/s


ZENBOOK:~$ ./scp-speed-test.sh root@99.99.99.141 61
Generating 61 KB test file...
Testing upload to root@99.99.99.141...
Testing download to root@99.99.99.141...
Removing test file on root@99.99.99.141...
Removing test file locally...

Upload speed:   77.13 KB/s
Download speed: 74.59 KB/s


ZENBOOK:~$ ./scp-speed-test.sh root@99.99.99.142 61
Generating 61 KB test file...
Testing upload to root@99.99.99.142...
Testing download to root@99.99.99.142...
Removing test file on root@99.99.99.142...
Removing test file locally...

Upload speed:   73.11 KB/s
Download speed: 73.85 KB/s
```

However, when repeating the above, but with **62** kilobytes, suddenly, two of them fail (.140 and .142):

```
ZENBOOK:~$ ./scp-speed-test.sh root@99.99.99.140 62
Generating 62 KB test file...
Testing upload to root@99.99.99.140...
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
Testing download to root@99.99.99.140...
Removing test file on root@99.99.99.140...
Removing test file locally...

Upload speed:    KB/s                <-----------------------------------
Download speed: 65.02 KB/s


ZENBOOK:~$ ./scp-speed-test.sh root@99.99.99.141 62
Generating 62 KB test file...
Testing upload to root@99.99.99.141...
Testing download to root@99.99.99.141...
Removing test file on root@99.99.99.141...
Removing test file locally...

Upload speed:   81.97 KB/s
Download speed: 75.92 KB/s


ZENBOOK:~$ ./scp-speed-test.sh root@99.99.99.142 62
Generating 62 KB test file...
Testing upload to root@99.99.99.142...
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
Testing download to root@99.99.99.142...
Removing test file on root@99.99.99.142...
Removing test file locally...

Upload speed:    KB/s                <-----------------------------------
Download speed: 57.48 KB/s
```

As seen above, both .140 and .142 are unable to receive the file properly. But, **.141** is the one having issues when sending large amounts of (1 MB+) data to any host.

Running `scp -vvv .scp-test-file root@99.99.99.140:.scp-test-file` on .140 with the 62 kilobytes file:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t .scp-test-file
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
Sending file modes: C0644 63488 .scp-test-file
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 33
Sink: C0644 63488 .scp-test-file
.scp-test-file                                                                                                                              0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
debug2: channel 0: written 33 to efd 7
```

It times out after about 20 seconds:

```
Sink: C0644 63488 .scp-test-file
.scp-test-file                                                                                                                              0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
debug2: channel 0: written 33 to efd 7
debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection reset by 99.99.99.140 port 22
lost connection
```

I've read https://superuser.com/questions/395356/scp-doesnt-work-but-ssh-does, but it's not that scp doesn't work, it merely doesn't work with anything over 62 kilobytes.

Another pointed in the direction of PMTU black holing, https://serverfault.com/questions/120505/problems-with-scp-stalling-during-file-copy-over-vpn, but I can find nothing that resembles that.

Running a diff on their network interfaces gives me nothing:

```
ZENBOOK:~$ diff <(ssh root@99.99.99.140 'ifconfig | grep mtu | grep -v veth') <(ssh root@99.99.99.141 'ifconfig | grep mtu | grep -v veth')
ZENBOOK:~$ diff <(ssh root@99.99.99.140 'ifconfig | grep mtu | grep -v veth') <(ssh root@99.99.99.142 'ifconfig | grep mtu | grep -v veth')
ZENBOOK:~$ diff <(ssh root@99.99.99.141 'ifconfig | grep mtu | grep -v veth') <(ssh root@99.99.99.142 'ifconfig | grep mtu | grep -v veth')
ZENBOOK:~$
```

How would I go about debugging this further?

edit: from the comments:

> To eliminate possible other causes, I'd first check that the login scripts on each target system won't output any messages or terminal control escape codes if the connection is not interactive. For example, if you run ssh root@99.99.99.140 /bin/true | od -t x1z, the output should be just 0000000 and nothing else. ... – telcoM yesterday

```
ZENBOOK:~$ ssh root@99.99.99.140 /bin/true | od -t x1z
0000000
ZENBOOK:~$ ssh root@99.99.99.141 /bin/true | od -t x1z
0000000
ZENBOOK:~$ ssh root@99.99.99.142 /bin/true | od -t x1z
0000000
```

Comment: You write "61 bytes" and "62 bytes", but the files actually used are 61 kilobytes and 62 kilobytes. In the script you use "mB" for megabytes, the correct abbreviation is MB (mB would be millibyte, quite meaningless). Please do the work of reducing the issue to something that can be shown by simple commands (or a really small script.

Comment: Okay, Thanks to the massive (and mostly irrelevant) block of text, I hadn't actually read the end of the question. It seems you are aware that you should reduce the problem, so ignore the last part of my comment above (can't edit it any longer).

Comment: To debug this further, run sshd with debug options on 140 and 142. What about other sizes than 62K?

Comment: The output shows you (for some reason that is quite unclear to me) get a "syntax error" when runnng the script, based on that I wouldn't bet on ssh being involved in the actual problem. But when you dug a bit deeper, it seemed that ssh timed out on the 62 kilobytes file? What about larger files, does it time out on those too?

Comment: To eliminate possible other causes, I'd first check that the login scripts on each target system won't output any messages or terminal control escape codes if the connection is not interactive. For example, if you run `ssh root@99.99.99.140 /bin/true | od -t x1z`, the output should be just `0000000` and nothing else. If you get more output than that, you should check the login scripts on the target system and make them so that anything that produces output is conditional on the shell session actually being an interactive one.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity Apologies about the bytes/kilobytes -- I realized that this morning when debugging further

Comment: Agreed. You need to fix the `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` first

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity The syntax error is caused by scp timing out, but the command is piped to grep and sed. Irrelevant to the case at hand I'm afraid

Comment: @telcoM The output is 000000 on all 3. I've edited my question to reflect that